# How to save a model record in Django

Tags: django

```
class Item(models.Model):
       id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)            
       userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)          
       categoryId = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       itemName = models.CharField(max_length=100)     
       startDate = models.DateTimeField('startDate')
       endDate = models.DateTimeField('endDate')       
       priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       own = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       advanced = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    item = Item.objects.create(request.user.id,categoryId,txtItemName,txtStartDate,txtEndDate,priorityName,progressStatus,ownStatus,advanced)
            item.save()
```

It is asking for a primary key field.
How to get the primary key field value during create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `id` field from your model, it's added automatically by Django.

`.save()` isn't necessary here, `.objects.create` already does that.

And it's better to use keyword arguments, then you can't make mistakes in the order of your arguments and people know what is what:

```
item = Item.objects.create(
  userId=request.user.id,
  categoryId=categoryId,
  itemName=txtItemName,
  startDate=txtStartDate,
  endDate=txtEndDate,
  priority=priorityName,
  progress=progressStatus,
  own=ownStatus,
  advanced=advanced)
```

You don't have to give a value then for the `id` field, as that is set automatically.

But wait: you're probably getting the error from the `userID` or `categoryID` fields. You should assign them an *instance* of the related field, or use the `_id` form of the field name:

```
userID=request.user,
categoryID_id=categoryId,
```

So the 'ID' part of those field names should be removed, this is confusing. Then it becomes:

```
user=request.user,
category_id=categoryId,
```

Comment: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: chandan>>": "Item.userId" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: You get that if you haven't accessed any attribute on the user yet, and so Django has postponed the decision of whether there actually is a current user.

Comment: You should probably check if the user is logged in (with request.user.is_authenticated()) because how else are you going to store a record for a user without user-id.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Apparently I had made another User model which was causing the problem!!! Thanks